# Python script for get data from merriam-webster

Tags: python, urllib

How can I get specific word's definition from merriam-webster using python's script? 
I have window with text box and button, and I want to print word's definition on the screen. 
thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help others answer your question better, please include some details as to what you have tried so far, i.e. some research.

Comment: Does it need to be mariam webster in particular? [Cambridge Dictionary appears to have a very usable api](http://dictionary-api.cambridge.org/api/demo)

Comment: Merriam-Webster also has an API. http://www.dictionaryapi.com/register/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
# Import libraries/ modules

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO)
import json
import requests

# write custom definition

def connect_mw_dictionary(api_key, word):
  logging.info("Connecting...")
  URL = "https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/sd2/json/"+word+"? 
  key="+api_key
  PARAMS = {'word': word,'key': api_key}
  r = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS)
  r.encoding = 'utf-8'
  if r.status_code == 200:
    logging.info("Connection successful.")
    return True, r.json()
  logging.info("Connection failed.")
  return False

def fetch_dictionary_result(res, lang, loc, audio_format, word):
  dict_txt = str(res[0]['def'][0]['sseq'][0][0][1]['dt'][0][1]).replace(" 
{bc}","")
  return dict_txt

api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxx" # replace with you api key
word = "keyword" # replace with word to lookup
lang = "en"
loc = "us"
audio_format = "mp3"
status, result = connect_mw_dictionary(api_key, word)
if status == True:
  status, dictionary_result = fetch_dictionary_result(result, lang, loc, 
audio_format, word)
```

dictionary_result

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score -2):

I am assuming merriam-webster is a website. Check if they an API. If so you can use it to achieve your task. If they do not have an API, I don't see how you can achieve your task without some highly advanced hacking, crawling algorithm. My suggestion is, as it appears you are trying to develop a dictionary type app, research dictionary websites that have open APIs.

Comment: Instead of telling the OP to check for an API, you should instead check yourself and then be able to give a more definitive answer (If they do, explain how to get the definition. If they don't, you can say so).

Comment: It doesn't necessarily matter how _you_ feel, as opposed to the StackOverflow community that you are writing this for.